# Help with this Lebesgue Integral Question

Tags: lebesgue-integral

Let $f_n = χ_{[n,2n]}$. Show that

> $$\lim_{n \to \infty } f_n(x) = 0$$

for  each  $x ∈ R $ but

> $$\lim_{n \to \infty } \int_R f_n \;\mathrm{dμ} \neq 0 =
> \int_R 0 \;\mathrm{dμ}$$

*Also  could  you  tell me  why  does  this does not  conflict   with   the   monotone   convergence   theorem?*

Comment: the $f_n$ are not increasing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be obvious that each function has non-zero integral, and specifically has integral $n$. Thus the limit of the integrals diverges and specifically isn't equal to $0$.

However, when you take the limit of the functions you get something uniformly $0$. To see this, notice that for every $x\in\mathbb{R},\forall n>|x|$, $f_n(x)=0$ holds. Thus the limit function is uniformity zero and so has zero integral.

This doesn't contradict the monotone convergence theorem because it's not monotone.